# How to convert an integer into char array and reverse to get the same number?

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I want to convert an integer into char array and retreive the same number from that char array.

Consider the number 20.
As 1 int(4 bytes) = 1 char,

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100  = (20) in decimal

___0 ___0 ___0 ___0 ___0 ___0 ___1 ___4  = hexadecimal representation

I want this pattern 00000014 to be stored in char array as 4 chars only as integer occupies 4 chars of space in such a way that the char array after converting into integer(can use sscanf()) will give the same result(20).

How do I do that?

Comment: You have tagged your question as both C and C++ instead of that language you are using. This is in contravention of the tags' usage directions. Please tag with only the language you are using, not multiple languages.

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentence "way that the char array after converting into integer(can use sscanf()) will give the same result(20)." (I'm using google translator), if my answer didn't help, please let me know so I can rectify the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [union](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-c/amp/)

```
union myUnion { 

    int x;
    char bytes[sizeof(int)]; 
};
```

And use it like:

```
union myUnion un;
un.x = 98632;
```

With this `un.bytes` hold the bytes of the integer 98632 in this case. If you change any of them, the change is reflected also in `un.x`, since everything in a `union` has a common memory location.

Conversion is handled automatically for you, if you want the `int` just get it by `un.x` and if you want the bytes get them by `un.bytes`. Whatever union member you change, the change is also made accordingly in its other members due to it being an `union`.

Comment: True @ikegami, 32 bits and 64 bits and moving the comment.

Comment: (It can even be as little as 16 bits)

Comment: @ikegami Your stretching it haha :-) but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Map each digit from 0 to 15 to it's equivalent 0 to f in hex. Apply a while loop taking remainder of the number when divided by 16 and append it to string and divide it by 16 in each step. The final string will be in reverse and I would keep it in reverse if there are operations to be done on it. If you want to print it, print it in reverse.

To convert the hex string back to int, reverse this procedure.

```
char mapping[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

void convert(string& s, int n)
{
    while (n)
    {
        int r = n % 16;
        s += mapping[r];
        n /= 16;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 20;
    string s;
    convert(s, n);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: I feel a C++ answer to a C question is suboptimal.

Comment: @alk hmm. They must have edited it because I search nothing except C++ tags on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are three most commonly used ways for these situations (without accounting for derived / anothers possibilities), two that use explicit conversions, and one that uses union

#### 1: Using conversions:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 22445;
  u_char b[4];
  *(uint32_t *)b = htonl((uint32_t)a);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%i;", b[i]);
}
```

**Result: 0;0;87;173;**

Explanation:

1. The htonl() function converts the unsigned integer hostlong from host byte order to network byte order, in a nutshell (for your use case), the `htonl` is to ensure that the integer is in [big-endian order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/little-and-big-endian-mystery/) before you store it. 
   Otherwise, if your machine is in the little-endian pattern, you would get the following result: 173;87;0;0;

Another possibility (using conversion):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 22445;
  u_char *b = (u_char*) &a;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%i;", b[i]);
}
```

**Result: 0;0;87;173;** (on big-endian machine), 
**Result: 173;87;0;0;** (on little-endian machine)

#### 2: Using union:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef union {
  u_char as_char[4];
  int as_int;
} U_INTCHAR; 

int main()
{
  U_INTCHAR ex;

  ex.as_int = 22445;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%i;", ex.as_char[i]);
}
```

**Result: 0;0;87;173;** (on big-endian machine), 
**Result: 173;87;0;0;** (on little-endian machine)

Explanation:

1. You need to use `unsigned char` because normal `char` can stores only -128 to 127, and the `unsigned char` version can store from 0 to 255 in C/C++

If you have any questions or if my answer is incomplete, feel free to comment on the post and I'll update the answer. :)